# Possible bug: setting colnames of an xts object in the last line of a function

Tags: r, xts

I have a R function that follows this form:

```
CreateXtsFromFile <- function(file)
{
    data <- read.table(file, sep = ",")
    data <- xts(data[, 1], order.by = data[, 1], unique = FALSE)
    # Manipulate the data
    colnames(data) <- c("a", "b", "c")
}
```

However, calling this function returns a character[3]:

```
data <- CreateXtsFromFile("file.txt")
str(test)
 chr [1:2] "a" "b"
```

However, after removing the final line in the function, the same call returns a xts.  The strange thing is that moving the final line to any other line in the function also returns a xts.  Has anyone come across this before?  I did a search on https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/ but didn't find anything.

Comment: Not a bug.  Read `help("function")`, which says, "If the end of a function is reached without calling ‘return’, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned."  Also, you could use `as.xts(read.zoo(...))` instead of writing a completely new function from scratch.

Comment: thanks, I'll make it a habit to explicitly call return at the end of my functions

Comment: You don't have to _explicitly_ call `return` at the end of every function, but you do have to make sure that the last evaluated expression in your function is what you want returned. E.g. this will return `x`: `f <- function(x) { names(x) <- NULL; x }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug.  `help("function")` tells you what is happening.  It says, "If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned."

So you need to return the `data` object:

```
CreateXtsFromFile <- function(file)
{
    data <- read.table(file, sep = ",")
    data <- xts(data[, 1], order.by = data[, 1], unique = FALSE)
    # Manipulate the data
    colnames(data) <- c("a", "b", "c")
    return(data)
}
```

Also, you could use `as.xts(read.zoo(...))` instead of writing a completely new function from scratch.